# Solve $\;\;y+(x^2y^3-x)y'=0;\;\;y(4)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I wish to solve $$\;y(x)+(x^2y(x)^3-x)y(x)'=0;\quad y(4)=1$$

It is supposed to be by multiplying by an integrand factor to turn it into an exact equation, but wolfram alpha gives these [solutions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%2b%28x%5E2y%5E3-x%29y%27=0) which don't look so good.

Is this problem OK or is there probably something wrong with it?

If it is ok, how can I solve it?

Comment: Bright colors can be $\color{red}{distracting}$, they may be good for emphasis in the right places, but I suggest to avoid them in the question title.

Comment: WA gives this solution because it always tries to express $y$ as a function of $x$. The solution does not look bad in implicit form.

Comment: anyone who has changed the title has my gratitude, my eyes were bleeding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: if we set $(x^2y^3-x)=N(x,y)$ and $M(x,y)=y$ then $$\frac{M_y-N_x}{N}$$ is a function respect to $x$. Indeed, you have the following integrating factor $$\mu(x)=x^{-2}$$

Comment: Nice hint, my friend, and generalizable too! +1

Comment: Hello, Babak! I'm just about heading to bed (too late for me!!) But I'm glad to see you, first!

Comment: @amWhy: $(:\prec )$ Hi

Comment: @amWhy: Are we supposed to choose or vote the moderators? Or it will be done by the system?

Comment: We well choose, when the nomination "phase" is over in 4 days. If there are 10 or more candidates four days from now, then there will be a primary starting in 4 days, otherwise, there is a time-frame within which we can vote. So, moderators are elected by "us all".

Comment: @BabakS.: I hope this nice answers gets to a nice answer badge! +1